# Xcode: App icon set has an unassigned child

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

I have an Xcode Bot that is giving the following warning after a successful build. As far as I can tell, there are no unassigned children in my "AppIcon" icon set. I also get no warnings when building locally. Have any ideas why I am getting this warning?

```
Bot Issue for AppIconWarningBot (warning in Assets.xcassets)
Integration #2 of AppIconWarningBot
Open in Xcode: xcbot://(null)/botID/7febe0d4926b6d03ecd9ea5bd5363cec/integrationID/7febe0d4926b6d03ecd9ea5bd53f092a

Assertion: The app icon set "AppIcon" has an unassigned child.
File: <...>/Resources/Assets.xcassets:(null)

Introduced 1 integration ago

Full logs for this integration are attached.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same warning until update Xcode to 7.2 on my server

That happens because 83.5px iPad Pro icon was added in AppIcon.assets starts from 7.2 Xcode only

Or maybe you really have *unassigned* images in your Assets.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm we are running Xcode 7.1. I'll try updating at some point. Thanks. Will report back with results.